# Renaming files that contain a pattern, looping through subfolders

Tags: python

I have a main folder, that contains multiple subfolders, that contain multiple files. I am trying to loop through subfolders and rename files that match a certain pattern. Here is what I have:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

pattern = "*z_2*"
pattern2 ='b_2.txt'
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\123'
list1= []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    list1+= [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]
    for i in list1:
        if fnmatch(i,pattern):
            a=os.path.join(path,i)
            b = os.path.dirname(i)
            os.rename(a, os.path.join(b,pattern2))
```

What I don't understand, is why, when I specify use os.**rename** , it is instead creating a text file in the specified subfolder, resulting in:

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ABC\\_100\\az_207.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ABC\\_100\\b_2.txt'
```

Comment: does the renamed file exists in that location?

Comment: Apparently a file with the name you want to rename to already exists. I'm not sure what you expect as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you rename a file, the destination filepath depends on `b`, which in turn depends only on the **`dirname`** part of `i`, not on `i` itself. So when your loop over `list1` finds more than one file in the same directory, they all get the same value for `os.path.join(b,pattern2)`. So your code is creating more than one file with the same name.

You probably want to reuse some part of `a` when building the destination filename, so as to ensure uniqueness.